# How to print flowdocument in landscape (WPF,C#)?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, flowdocument

I'd like to print my programmatically created flowdocument in landscape mode and I tried all versions what I've found but none of them works. 
Here's my code below:

```
try
            {
                // Create a PrintDialog 
                PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
                printDlg.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = System.Printing.PageOrientation.Landscape;


                // Create a FlowDocument dynamically. 
                FlowDocument doc = CreateFlowDocumentSum();
                doc.Name = "FlowDoc";
                doc.ColumnWidth = printDlg.PrintableAreaWidth;

                // Create IDocumentPaginatorSource from FlowDocument 
                IDocumentPaginatorSource idpSource = doc;



                // Call PrintDocument method to send document to printer 

                printDlg.PrintDocument(idpSource.DocumentPaginator, "sum");
                doc.Blocks.Clear();
                sumTable.Clear();

            }
            catch
            { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it finally.
Just modified the code in the print button event:

```
PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
                LocalPrintServer ps = new LocalPrintServer();
                PrintQueue pq = ps.DefaultPrintQueue;

                PrintTicket pt = pq.UserPrintTicket;

                    pt.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;

                FlowDocument doc = CreateFlowDocumentSum();


                doc.PageHeight = 768;
                doc.PageWidth = 1104;

                PageMediaSize pageMediaSize = new PageMediaSize(doc.PageWidth, doc.PageHeight);
                    pt.PageMediaSize = pageMediaSize;
                    IDocumentPaginatorSource source = doc as IDocumentPaginatorSource;


                printDlg.PrintDocument(source.DocumentPaginator, "sum");
```

Then in my FlowDocument I set the width and height:

```
FlowDocument docSum = new FlowDocument();
        docSum.PageHeight = 768;
        docSum.PageWidth = 1104;
        docSum.ColumnWidth = 1104;
```

Comment: This solution uses the "Reach" reference (namespace). Isn't there any solution, not needing additional references?